# Get days of the month of specific year with - moment JS and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, momentjs

I trying to create a custom date picker in angular with the help of moment JS.
The issue that i cant get the days of the correct month when the year is changing

The `getDaysArrayByMonth()` returning the months only of 2018

```
  public selectedMonth: any
  private monthIterator = 0
  public daysOfSelectedMonth = [];
  public monthDaysAmount: number

  onNextMonth() {
    this.monthIterator++
    this.selectedMonth = moment().add(this.monthIterator, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY');
    this.getDaysArrayByMonth()
  }

  onPreviousMonth() {
    this.monthIterator--
    this.selectedMonth = moment().add(this.monthIterator, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY');
    this.getDaysArrayByMonth()

  }

  getDaysArrayByMonth(){
    this.daysOfSelectedMonth = []
    this.monthDaysAmount = moment().month(this.selectedMonth).daysInMonth() ;
    const remainingToEvenRows = 35 - this.monthDaysAmount
    const days = this.monthDaysAmount + remainingToEvenRows

    for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
      this.daysOfSelectedMonth.push(moment().month(this.selectedMonth).date(i + 1).format('Do MMMM YYYY'));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.selectedMonth is saving the month and the year so you should use the result in the moment constructor:

`moment(this.selectedMonth, 'MMMM YYYY')`

```
this.monthDaysAmount = moment(this.selectedMonth, 'MMMM YYYY').daysInMonth() ;
for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
  this.daysOfSelectedMonth.push(moment(this.selectedMonth, 'MMMM YYYY').date(i + 1).format('Do MMMM YYYY'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `moment()` function always returns the current date so if you are building logic on it will always return the current month and year. so you have to specify the year as well as month inside the constructor to return the desired/past month.

so change this code as follows

```
/// public selectedMonth: any
private monthIterator = 0
public daysOfSelectedMonth = [];
public monthDaysAmount: number

onNextMonth() {
this.monthIterator++
/// this.selectedMonth = moment().add(this.monthIterator, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY');
this.getDaysArrayByMonth(moment("201501", "YYYYMM").add(1, 'months').format('YYYYMM'));
}

onPreviousMonth() {
this.monthIterator--
/// this.selectedMonth = moment().add(this.monthIterator, 'months').format('MMMM YYYY');

this.getDaysArrayByMonth(moment("201501", "YYYYMM").add(1, 'months').format('YYYYMM'))
}

getDaysArrayByMonth(yearMonth: string){
this.daysOfSelectedMonth = []
/// this.monthDaysAmount = moment().month(this.selectedMonth).daysInMonth() ;
this.monthDaysAmount = moment(yearMonth,'YYYYMM').daysInMonth() ;
const remainingToEvenRows = 35 - this.monthDaysAmount
const days = this.monthDaysAmount + remainingToEvenRows

for (let i = 0; i < days; i++) {
  this.daysOfSelectedMonth.push(moment().month(this.selectedMonth).date(i + 1).format('Do MMMM YYYY'));
}
```

}

Please remove the hard coded `201501` and pass the YearMonth combo to the function `onNextMonth` and `onPreviousMonth`.

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-53355987?embed=1&file=index.html)